# mysql restore 2013 Lost connection to the mysql server

Tags: mysql, timeout, restore

I did a backup. The dump is 240 GB. This is the command that I executed 
mysql -u dba -p < XXX.sql
After 1 hours of the restore I had this error

```
 '2013 Lost connection to the mysql server during the query'
```

After google I changed this 2 paramet
max_allowed_packet = 2148M and net_write_timeout =  10000
But unfortunatelly I always the same errors.
I also tried to add this config in the my.cnf `innodb_force_recovery = 1`
I had the error

```
Error 1036 at ine 2863: Table  XXX is read only
```

Thanks you in advance for your help

Comment: `innodb_force_recovery` is not for that purpose. Its a good idea to read the manual before amending potentially dangerous `my.cnf` parameters

Comment: What type of database engine is in use? Also, is the error on a specific table every time? It may well not be related to the load operation but, instead, related to enabling indexes or other operations which would be draining other resources than those you have identified.

Comment: Hi @glenstar this this is a innodb the  '2013 Lost connection to the mysql server during the query' is evry time